Regarding derivation of the scalar curvature in general relativity
As usual, my general relativity textbook(Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell, A. Zee) defines the scalar curvature as follows.
$$
R(x) \equiv g^{\rho\nu}(x)R_{\rho\nu}(x) \cdots (1)
$$
Next, the text utilizes the following equation for Einstein’s field equation.
$$
g_{\mu\nu}(X)R^{\mu\nu}(x) = R(x) \cdots(2)
$$
I can understand (1) as the definition of the scalar curvature. However, I can’t understand why (2) holds.
I would be most grateful if someone gives me an explanation of (2).

We have
$$
R^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\sigma}g^{\nu\tau}R_{\sigma\tau}
$$
and
$$
g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\sigma}=g_{\nu\mu}g^{\mu\sigma}=\delta_\nu^\sigma.
$$
Therefore
$$
g_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\sigma}g^{\nu\tau}R_{\sigma\tau}= \delta_\nu^\sigma g^{\nu\tau} R_{\sigma\tau}=g^{\sigma\tau} R_{\sigma\tau}.
$$

I understood it. Thank you very much.
